# Printing elements of a long array gives wrong output,

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am trying to write a function which takes in size of list and upper range (for random number) and return the random numbers in array.
Here is what I wrote.

```
bool inList(long *heads, int num, int s){
    for (int i=0; i<s; i++){
        if (heads[i] == num){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

long* generateRandomList(size_t s, int n){
    long heads[s];
    for (long i=0; i<s; i++){
        heads[i] = -1;
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++){
        int r;
        while (true){
            r = ( rand() % n ) + 1;

            bool isInList = inList(heads, r, s); // unique numbers

            if (isInList == false){
                break;
            }
        }
        heads[i] = r;
        printf("i %d r %d\n", i, r); // this is ok

    }
    return heads;
}



int main(){
    size_t s = 20;
    size_t n = 100;
    long *lists;
    lists = generateRandomList(s, n);

for (int i=0; i<s;i++){
      printf("%d, %d\n",i, lists[i] );
  }
```

}

The first printf inside `generateRandomList()` works fine..
But, the second one produces some garbage values..
Here is the sample output.

```
// from printf inside generateRandomList function
i 0 r 16
i 1 r 4
i 2 r 11
i 3 r 20
i 4 r 5
i 5 r 14
i 6 r 3
i 7 r 6
i 8 r 17
// from second printf.
0, 16
1, 16
2, -712138747
3, 1
4, 5
5, 14
6, 3
7, 6
8, 17
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you can compile this code. Are the last several lines of code outside all functions?

Comment: @YuHao: Edited.. I just snipped out the relevant portion of the code.. apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I believe

```
printf("%d, %d\n",i, heads[i] );
```

should read

```
printf("%d, %d\n",i, lists[i] );
```

which is a typo in *this* code snippet.

---

Coming to the problem(s), in your code, **firstly,** `heads` array is local to the function `generateRandomList()`. That is why, the first `printf()` inside the function produces correct output by accessing `heads` array.

Once the function is finished,  and you `return` the address of the local variable, that becomes invalid after the return. So, accessing the returned pointer in the caller function is essentially accessing invalid memory and  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That is the reason for the *garbage* values being printed out in case of the second print.

Solution: If you need to `return` a pointer from a function and use that in the caller, you have to define a pointer and allocate memory using dynamic memory allocation APIs, like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

*Knock Knock: Don't forget [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free), also.*

**Next**, using a wrong type of argument for a format sopecifier also invokes UB. `%d` expects an argument of type `int` but you're passing a `long` there.

Solution: `long` needs to have `%ld` format specifier with `printf()`.

Comment: @Sourov Ghosh.. Edited the heads to list

Comment: @Fraz Now I'm confident you have _issues_ with correct spelling. :P (I'm Sourav)

Comment: I have changed the printf types to ld.. but still see the same issue

Comment: @Fraz Please read my updated answer. Mismatched format specifier is not the _only_ issue in your code.

Comment: Yep yep. malloc fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dynamic arrays that have no clean way of telling you that you may not have enough memory (in this case on the stack). Your program thus occasionally may dump core.

More important, you return a local automatic variable from a no longer existing function on the stack and this will be overwritten by the next function call.

Avoid to use dynamic arrays except for very limited cases where you know that the stacksize will be sufficient.

If you like to return a persistent array, use malloc() instead of dynamic arrays.